ASP.NET Core HtmlHelper TextBoxFor with Decimal Type Returns Zero for Decimal Values
I have two pieces of code for creating a number input field for a decimal property called Price in my ASP.NET Core application.
The first code snippet using asp-for works perfectly:
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Price" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" type="number" step="0.01" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

However, when I try to achieve the same functionality using the HtmlHelper class, it does not work as expected:
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Price, new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price, new
                                   {
                                       @class = "form-control",
                                       type = "number",
                                       step = "0.01"
                                   })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>

With the second code snippet, when I enter decimal values (e.g., 0.06), it sends 0 back to the Price property on form submission, and I get the following validation error:

The value '0.06' is not valid for Price

Question: what could be causing this issue with the second code snippet? How can I ensure that the HtmlHelper version correctly handles decimal values in the form input?

Hi @knorbika,It works fine in my side. Are you sure there is no conflict element in your view? I suggest you share the whole view code and model design.
